# Find the angle what which the light enters and the length of its path inside the prism.

Tags: geometry

> A regular triangular prism has height $h$ and a base of side length $a$. Both bases have small holes in the centers, and the inside of the there vertical walls has a mirror surface. Light enters through the small hole in the top base, strikes each vertical wall once and leaves the hole in the bottom. Find the angle what which the light enters and the length of its path inside the prism.

I was thinking of the $2$D equivalent of this question, which is like the pool table where you can draw a straight line since it is a reflection. Even if that were the case here we would have to parameterize the line so it might still be possible. Otherwise I am not sure how to go about this question because I don't see how it can hit all three walls.